# PHP emulating POST data on local files

Tags: php, curl, pci-compliance

I know cURL is primarily for fetching data from remote sites. Should you use cURL to get data from local urls that use POST data?

For example, i have a page the displays a receipt.  i use this to send html emails and also for the customer to view the receipt in their browser if their email client isn't displaying it correctly.

If POST cardholder data is present it will display the first name, last name, address, city, state, zip, phone, email, and method of payment in the receipt.

I use the file_get_contents() function to retrieve that web page and send the email. The problem: No POST data is present when doing that so if you're the one getting the receipt email, your billing information won't be on it. There's no way to prove that the receipt is actually yours.

I'm trying to comply with PCI standards so i'm trying to avoid storing cardholder data in sessions or a database table.

Comment: are you kidding me? I think your looking for include() because what your saying is useless. No one will ever have their server send a post request to itself, leave that up to the client script.

Comment: then how would you go about including data in a web page that you don't want to store in a session or database table?

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using file_get_contents() could you not just use include or require in the script where you're pulling in that file?  Then prior to that you could manually set the $_POST vars and the included file would fire the email and include the user data.

```
//Script where you're calling file_get_contents()

$_POST['firstName'] = $firstName;
$_POST['lastName'] = $lastName;
//etc for all fields

include "your_email_script";
```

Comment: Finding this answer took more effort than it should have. There are many posts, like Adam's above, where people say it's stupid to POST to a script on your own server, BUT if you are using a script that requires POST, how to avoid that without killing kittens?? TheOx gave the simple solution. Thanks!